# With & WhereHas returning empty nested relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent query which to my understanding should return Categories that have relations to attribute sets, which in turn have relations to attributes, which in turn have relationships to variants.

```
$attributes = Category::with(['attributeSets.attributes.variants' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', 1)->withPivot('value');
        }])->whereHas('attributeSets.attributes.variants', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', 1);
        })->get()->toArray();
```

However, I receive the following which appears to include attributes with no relation to variants (e.g.) *"variants" => []*.

How can I remove these attributes?

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "parent_id" => null
    "category_type_id" => null
    "name" => "harum"
    "identifier" => "harum"
    "slug" => "harum"
    "sort_order" => 0
    "is_active" => 0
    "created_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
    "updated_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
    "parent" => null
    "attribute_sets" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "ex"
        "identifier" => "ex"
        "created_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
        "updated_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
        "mainCategory" => array:12 [▶]
        "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
        "attributes" => array:3 [▼
          0 => array:8 [▼
            "id" => 1
            "attribute_set_id" => 1
            "name" => "minus"
            "identifier" => "minus"
            "created_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "updated_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "set" => array:6 [▶]
            "variants" => []
          ]
          1 => array:8 [▼
            "id" => 2
            "attribute_set_id" => 1
            "name" => "ducimus"
            "identifier" => "ducimus"
            "created_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "updated_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "set" => array:6 [▶]
            "variants" => []
          ]
          2 => array:8 [▼
            "id" => 3
            "attribute_set_id" => 1
            "name" => "mollitia"
            "identifier" => "mollitia"
            "created_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "updated_at" => "2019-12-11 15:45:51"
            "set" => array:6 [▶]
            "variants" => array:1 [▶]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

My models:

**Category**

```
public function attributeSets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeSet::class, 'attribute_set_categories');
    }
```

**AttributeSet**

```
public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }
```

**Attribute**

```
public function variants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'variant_attributes');
    }
```

Comment: nothing immediately sticks out at me as being wrong here but I would try switching the order of the `whereHas` and `with` methods, if they execute in the order listed in the post it may try to load all the Categories first, with them, then filter down

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately swapping them around results in the same output - Odd!